# Insert data into a master table by considering the data with order by

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `SubCategory` which data like this:

[image]

I have written an insert script to insert the `distinct CategoryName` into another table:

```
INSERT INTO Category (CategoryName)
    SELECT CategoryName 
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
             CategoryName, 
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryName, orderby ORDER BY orderby) AS Row 
         FROM SubCategory fr
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Category fr1 
                           WHERE fr1.CategoryName = fr.CategoryName)) x
```

I am able to get the distinct results but the `categoryName` should be inserted in the `orderby` column on the subcategory table

Here is the fiddle I am working on

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/54974/2

Comment: It makes no sense to order the data in an insert - rows in a relational database table are unordered; any ordering would only make sense if it were used to calculate an additional column where you also specified the order or rank of each category; when you want to retrieve rows in a particular order, you do that as part of the data retrieval operation.

Comment: Your insert statement must have an order by clause if you want those inserts to generate identity values in a specific order. Why would you expect anything else? Rows in a table are, by definition, unordered. Here you try to force identity value to be generated in a specific way probably based on this incorrect order assumption. But you also overlook the issue with future changes to this table - order and identity values will eventually get "out of sync".

Comment: Now i see you don't use an identity column anywhere. I leave the first comment since you likely will fall under that illusion at some later date. But the primary point remains. Rows in a table have no defined order. If you need order in a resultset, then the query generating that resultset must contain an ORDER BY clause. Otherwise, you are declaring you don't care about the order and the data engine is free to return rows any way it wants. Usually that is based on how the rows are accessed - which can change based on runtime factors.

Comment: It has no real bearing to order the inserted data even if you are trying to align the data with an identity column - while retrieving rows from a table *usually* means they are ordered by the clustered key, the query optimizer is under no obligation to do so and this can change as a result of join logic or parallelism, you cannot reliably assume any ordering to rows unless explicitely specified.

Answer (score 0):

Order in inserted data have no matter by design of SQL language. You should create primary index key in the new table to sort it by this index.

Comment: A primary key does not "sort" rows. And you likely assume the primary key is the clustered key here as well - not a safe assumption either.

Comment: A clustered key (not necessarily a primary key) *physically* stores rows in key order, this is not guaranteed to be the case when the rows are retrieved; queries cannot make any assumption about the data's physical representation!

Comment: Ok, may be it not clear: use key for order with select statement, SQL never order reading unless you declare 'order by' while reading

Answer (score 0):

You can use cte or temp table and run order by over it

```
CREATE TABLE SubCategory
(
  RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  SubCategoryName NVARCHAR(500),
  CategoryName NVARCHAR(500),
  OrderBy INT
)

CREATE TABLE Category
(
  RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  CategoryName NVARCHAR(500)  
)

INSERT INTO SubCategory
VALUES ('SubCategory1', 'Category', 1), ('SubCategory2', 'Category', 1),
('SubCategory1', 'Another', 2), ('SubCategory2', 'Another', 2),
('SubCategory2', 'Bowled', 3)


;WITH cteorder AS
     (
     SELECT DISTINCT 
             CategoryName,Orderby            
         FROM SubCategory fr       
     )
     

INSERT INTO Category (CategoryName)
SELECT CategoryName FROM  cteorder ORDER BY Orderby
```